# Convert array to object based on set of keys using lodash or underscore js

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I have a requirement to convert an array to object based on values in another array using lodash or underscore js.

```
var connections = [ 'facebook', 'twitter', 'linkedin', 'xing', 'weibo' ];

var contents = [
    {
        preview_image_url: "http://www.ideacellular.com/ISC/images/banners/home-page/banner1.jpg",
        preview_title: "title of the message1",
        facebook: "fb first 22 once more",
        preview_description: "Home↵How to↵How to find a Place in KeralaHow to find a place in Kerala"
    },
    {
        linkedin: "test linkedin",
        preview_image_url: "http://www.ideacellular.com/ISC/images/banners/home-page/banner2.jpg",
        preview_title: "linkedin title2",
        preview_description: "linkedin description 2"
    },
    {
        preview_image_url: "http://www.ideacellular.com/ISC/images/banners/home-page/banner3.jpg",
        preview_title: "linkedin title3",
        preview_description: "linkedin description 3",
        twitter: "test twitter"
    }
];
```

My requirement is to loop through connections array and if any of connections present in contents array create a result ojbect with those connection name.

**Expected result**

```
var result = {
    facebook: {
        preview_image_url: "http://www.ideacellular.com/ISC/images/banners/home-page/banner1.jpg",
        preview_title: "title of the message1",
        facebook: "fb first 22 once more",
        preview_description: "Home↵How to↵How to find a Place in KeralaHow to find a place in Kerala"
    },
    linkedin: {
        linkedin: "test linkedin",
        preview_image_url: "http://www.ideacellular.com/ISC/images/banners/home-page/banner2.jpg",
        preview_title: "linkedin title2",
        preview_description: "linkedin description 2"
    },
    twitter: {
        preview_image_url: "http://www.ideacellular.com/ISC/images/banners/home-page/banner3.jpg",
        preview_title: "linkedin title3",
        preview_description: "linkedin description 3",
        twitter: "test twitter"
    }
};
```

Your help is much appreciated. I have tried some usual looping using forEach, is there any simple way to do it using underscore js or lodash. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
var result = {};

connections.forEach(function (key) {
    contents.forEach(function (el) {
        if (el[key] && !result[key]) {
            result[key] = el;
        }
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

[`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/z5Lq84zm/)

Comment: Thank you so much for you help. God bless you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [indexBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#indexBy) and [intersection()](https://lodash.com/docs#intersection) for this:

```
_.indexBy(contents, function(item) {
    return _(item)
        .keys()
        .intersection(connections)
        .first();
});
```

The idea is that you find the intersection between the keys of the `contents` item, and the `connections` array. If such an intersection exists, you use that value as the indexing key.